# Figuring out CRS of ArcGIS Pro reprojection

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, arcgis-pro

I'm using ArcGIS Pro to reproject my raster from EPSG:27700 (British National Grid) to EPSG:3857 (WGS84)

The Geographic Transformation says `OSGB_1936_To_ETRS_1989_1 + ETRS_1989_To_WGS_1984`

How do I do such a transformation in GDAL?

I can't seem to figure out the correct EPSG codes for `ETRS_1989_1` and `ETRS_1989`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reprojection is done in some steps:

- Unproject from British National Grid (EPSG:27700) to OSGB36 (EPSG:4277).
- Transform from OSGB36 to ETRS89 (EPSG:4258), using [OSGB36 to ETRS89 (1) - (EPSG:5338)](https://epsg.org/transformation_5338/OSGB36-to-ETRS89-1.html).
- Transform from ETRS89 to WGS84 (EPSG:4326), using [ETRS89 to WGS 84 (1) - (EPSG:1149)](https://epsg.org/transformation_1149/ETRS89-to-WGS-84-1.html).
- Project from WGS84 to WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG:3857).

You can do it with *gdalwarp* and the *-ct* parameter (PROJ coordinates transformation pipeline). To know the pipelines use *projinfo*:

```
$ projinfo -s EPSG:27700 -t EPSG:4277 -o PROJ
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

INVERSE(EPSG):19916, Inverse of British National Grid, 0 m, United Kingdom (UK) - offshore to boundary of UKCS within 49°45'N to 61°N and 9°W to 2°E; onshore Great Britain (England, Wales and Scotland). Isle of Man onshore.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000
        +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
```

```
$ projinfo EPSG:5338 -k operation -o PROJ
PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=OSTN02_NTv2.gsb
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
```

```
$ projinfo EPSG:1149 -k operation -o PROJ
PROJ string:
+proj=noop
```

```
$ projinfo -s EPSG:4326 -t EPSG:3857 -o PROJ
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

EPSG:3856, Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator, 0 m, World.

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84
```

Maybe some intermediate axis swaps and unit conversions can be omitted, but I would leave them as they are, joining one after the other. The no operation between ETRS89 and WGS84 can be omitted too. All you need is the OSTN02_NTv2.gsb grid file in your PROJ installation.

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "EPSG:27700" -t_srs "EPSG:3857" -ct "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=OSTN02_NTv2.gsb +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84" input.tif output.tif
```